# Как в программе узнать, есть ли в CPU Hyper-threading ?

Tags: cpu, linux

Подозреваю, что это можно взять из `/proc/cpuinfo`, возможно из:

```
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc rep_good pni ssse3 lahf_lm
```

или из другого места (?), навскидку ничего больше из /proc/cpuinfo не подходит.

На первый взгляд флаг **ht** говорит о Hyper-threading. Но, это I5-2500, а в его описании сказано, что 4 core без Hyper-Threading. Поэтому ht это скорее всего Hyper-Transport. [Здесь](http://blog.incase.de/index.php/cpu-feature-flags-and-their-meanings) сказано, что Hyper-Threading это **HTT/HT** (видимо иногда метят по разному ?).

Собственно интересен также AMD аналог (не знаю как называется).

***Никто не знает, что и где точно смотреть в Linux?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы установить поддержку Hyper-Threading, нужно [проверить](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/counting-physical-and-logical-32-bit-processors/) CPUID (genuine Intel CPU) и значение бита № 28 регистра EDX (установлен в 1). По ссылке можно скачать утилиту CPUCount, которая как-то работает с Hyper-Threading.

Comment: Спасибо, но мне для хотелось бы иметь способ для "библиотечной" функции (прочесть разок при первом вызове /proc/cpuinfo или вызвать что-то вроде sysinfo()).

Comment: @cool, Еще раз спасибо (огромное, ответ принял). Из Вашей информации нашел ссылку:

    http://softpixel.com/~cwright/programming/simd/cpuid.php

По ней написал программку, но получается, что HTT у меня есть (?). Надо отдельно разбираться.

Может я не тот бит тестирую (?) написано бит 28, делаю маску 1<<28, получаю, что в 1 (в флагах /proc/cpuinfo похоже он именован **ht**).

Вопрос пока не закрываю, может кто еще чего подскажет.

Answer (score 2):

1. флаг ht действительно говорит о наличии у процессора возможности HyperThreading.
2. есть поле cpu cores - оно говорит о числе реальных ядер, есть поле siblings - оно говорит о числе виртуальных ядер. По их соотношению можно узнать о наличии HyperThreading и о числе потоков на одно физическое ядро.

Comment: @mikillskegg, благодарю Вас.

--

cpu cores: 4
siblings:  4

В спецификации INTEL [Intel® Core™ i5-2500 Processor 
(6M Cache, 3.30 GHz)](http://ark.intel.com/products/52209/Intel-Core-i5-2500-Processor-%286M-Cache-3_30-GHz%29)

\# of Cores 4
\# of Threads 4

Т.о. для того, чтобы узнать количество одновременно выполняемых threads надо смотреть siblings?

Собственно меня интересует **не только этот** компьютер, а что посмотреть при запуске на любом x-86 ?

Comment: получается, так. но это говорит только о включенном HT. Я проэкспериментировал на своем компе (Core i7). В нормальном режиме siblings 8 cpu cores 4, при отключенном в BIOS HT siblings 4 cpu cores 4.

Comment: Похоже так. Завтра еще на работе на Dual-Core посмотрю...

А в flags **ht** у Вас в обоих случаях есть ?

Comment: угу, на обоих

Comment: а я завтра на Athlon64 посмотрю.

Comment: Посмотрел на Dual-Core в VirtuaBox виртуальная машина с 1 cpu (с 2-мя под VirtualBox linux не запускается, VBox ругается на отсутствие некоторых команд VT-x. Наверное из-за 32-bit Windows XP).

--

Вообще новости...  

В /proc/cpuinfo **нет** строк cpu cores и sibling (видимо потому что 1 cpu). В flags **нет ht**.

--

НО, программка чтения CPUID **обнаруживает флаг HTT** и программка с 2-мя pthreads в параллель своим поведением (печатает времена исполнения вычислений) подтверждает это.

***дальнейшие комментарии только в дополнениях к вопросу. Лимит-с***

Comment: AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2

siblings 2

cpu cores 2

ht выставлен.